# Default nth argument with Python ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

I would like to create python program, that can accept `--add` flag with 2 or 3 arguments.

```
./script.py --add a 1
./script.py --add a 2 c
```

Is there any way to set `nargs` in `ArgumentParser` to 2 or 3 and if there are only 2 args, set the 3rd one to `a` value? I know that there is `+` option, but when I use this:

- I cannot set `metavar` for 3 arguments (`metavar = ("First", "Second", "Third")`) because of:

> ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs

- I have to make my own arg validation (user can enter 30 args or only 1 arg),
- I have to parse args to required types manually,
- I have to set default value of 3rd argument manually, if not exist.

Here is my current code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--add", nargs = "+", metavar = ("First", "Second"))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Program prints args:

```
./script.py --add a 2
# Namespace(add=['a', '2'])
# Second argument should be number, not a string.
# Third argument should be 'a' (default value if 3rd value is not entered).

./script.py --help
# ... -a First [Second ...], --add First [Second ...] ...
# There should be also label for 3rd arg like that: --add First [Second [Third]]
```

Comment: If you have an option that takes an open-ended number of arguments, it has to be the *last* option on the command line. It either swallows all remaining arguments, or you have to use `--` to signal the end of *all* option parsing.

Comment: You are usually better off just defining two separate options (possibly in a mutually exclusive group), one that takes exactly 2 arguments and another that takes exactly 3.

Comment: Is the `--add` required? Do you take any positional arguments? Because you could try adding 3rd as optional positional. The downside is it would also allow for things like `script.py third --add first second`... The best thing would be to make a custom Action or, like you said, do things manually. I'd recommend encapsulating the latter in a function to make things simple.

Comment: +I think you should re-think the way you want this parser to behave. Second argument is a number, but you can't really have different types automatically parsed without any code from you. So it's either custom code or breaking the thing into more arguments.